# Remove actionbar menu item when closing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using the code from the Example section of this page http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

In landscape mode, the activity displays two fragments side-by-side, and on rotation, it launches a new activity containing the "detail" fragment.

The problem is that if I add a menu item to the actionbar from the detail fragment then rotate the screen to portrait to launch the detail fragment in a new activity then exit the activity, the menu item is still displayed even though the fragment supplying the menu item has been removed.

I've tried removing the detail fragment with a FragmentTransaction in onResume and then calling invalidateOptionsMenu(), but it doesn't remove the menu item.

I'm using ActionBarSherlock, and I've also tried supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I was removing the fragment, but I wasn't.  After removing the fragment in onResume, my problem was solved.